# If using Ruby on Rails, how to use 1 code base for 2 websites for the HTML elements' IDs and class names to be different?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, sass

If using Ruby on Rails, we can set a config file to have all the different header titles, phrases, so as to different phrases on 2 different websites.
But how about the IDs and class names (in `.erb` or `.haml`, and in `.sass` or `.css`)?

(The reason to use particular category names for the IDs and classes is so that search engines can better index the site (to see what actual content is on the site))

In `.haml` it is something like

```
#sport-watches-list
```

which is the same as

```
<div id="sport-watches-list">
```

and there is corresponding .sass or .css styles that go with it.  So if the other website is

```
#fancy-cars-list
```

How do we make it work on Ruby on Rails? It is because there can be many such names in one page, and there are several types of pages for each website, with either watches or cars in the name:

```
#fancy-cars-list
  #fancy-car-row
    #fancy-car-photo
    #fancy-car-name
    #fancy-car-rating
```

We can have a general file with

```
#product-category-list
```

and all the markups, and use a script to replace all of them to either watches or cars, and do it also to the .sass files, but it will be quite messy.  Is there a better way?

The reason to use particular category names for the IDs and classes is so that search engines can better index the site (to see what actual content is on the site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to structure your id's and class names for Search Engines as search engines [do not use](http://www.quora.com/Does-the-inclusion-of-keywords-inside-class-and-id-tags-help-SEO) this markup.  You're time is better spent ensuring the content of each site is great.

Build sites for users not search engines, and the search engines will follow ;)

Comment: really... but I always heard that don't use `div` but use `h1` so that search engines can pick up your content better.  Also, before HTML5 using `<nav>` and semantic tags, I thought the way to use HTML4 with semantics is usually by class names or ID names

Comment: that's true, using correct html elements results in better SEO (and better structured code for your users), but classes and IDs are really only used by your CSS.

Comment: are you sure?  I heard that search engines use `<ul class="nav">` to detect the content inside is for menu bar items on the webpage

Comment: yes, I'm sure.  What you heard is not true.  You can call that ul class anything you like (from an SEO perspective).  Search engines will look at your actual content not your markup classes and ids.

Comment: is there actually any docs/reference that says google/yahoo/bing don't use them?  Because a person is saying: it won't, but I can write a search engine today that does look at it... also I thought the whole point of HTML5 having `<nav>` is in that same direction

Comment: <nav> is a html element whereas "id" and "class" are html attributes.  Html elements are used by search engines to ascertain either relevance or significance of the content within them.  Html attributes are not.

Comment: same question: any search engine can care about the id name or class name if it chooses to.  So any docs that says they don't (at least all the big search engines don't)